# How can I speed up image load time in my web site?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, image, preload

I am currently developing a web site with PHP + MySQL and jQuery. So far I have been doing it in my local machine. I notice that when I see the page the images on it take some time to load (few time but its visible). All images are small (PNG's with less than 3 KB). Now, when I load the page, there are some database connections happening in order to get some data that I will display.

I am not sure if this loading time issue has something to do with the amount of images, or with the time that the PHP script + the DB connections take to execute. (I have very little data in my database so I wouldn't assume this case.)

My question is: Is it a good approach to preload all the images in the beginning of each page? I tried it with jQuery and it works fine. I'm just not sure which disadvantages I can get with it. For example, to do so, I need to include the jQuery library in the beginning of the page? I thought it was a bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

If these PNGs are stored in the database as BLOBs — not clear from your question — don't do that.  Serving images from a DB through PHP is not as efficient as letting the web server serve them straight from the filesystem.  If the images are tied to particular records, just name the PNG after the row ID, so you can find it in a directory dedicated to storing those images. The PHP code then just generates the URL that points to the PNG file on disk, so the web server can send them statically.

I don't think preloading the images within the same page is going to buy you anything.  If anything, it might slow the *apparent* overall page load time because the browser can only retrieve a fixed number of resources concurrently, typically 2-4.  Loading images at the top of the `<body>` means there are other things at the top of the page "above the fold" that have to wait for some HTTP connection slots to free up.  Better to let the images load in their natural order.

Preloading makes sense in two situations:

- The image isn't shown by default, but is expected to be needed as the user interacts with the page.  Good examples of this are the hover and click state images for rollovers.
- The image isn't used on this page, but will be needed on the next.  Good examples of this are any site where there is a clear progression from one page to the next, like in a shopping cart.

Either way, do the preload at the very *bottom* of the `<body>`, so everything else loads first.

Having addressed those two issues, run [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) on your site. It started out as a plugin for [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com), which in turn is a plugin for Firefox, but it's since been ported to all major browsers except IE.

The beauty of YSlow is that it detects common slowdowns automatically, just by loading the page while the extension is active.  It then gives you a clear grade for the page, so you can judge when you're "done" optimizing.  If you're below an **A**, you're not done yet. :)  It's not uncommon to see sites rating a **D** or worse, because the default configuration for web servers is conservative to avoid causing problems.  Fixing YSlow warnings is generally pretty easy, but you have to be careful to avoid creating caching and other problems, which is why the default server config doesn't do these things.

Another answer recommended the [Google PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) offering. It's available as a plugin for Chrome and Firefox, as a server-side Apache module, and as a Google-hosted service. I have no idea how it compares to YSlow, but it looks interesting.

Also consider using the browser's debugger to get a waterfall graph of resource load times:

- In Firebug you get this in the Net tab.
- In Safari, you get to it via the Develop menu, which is normally disabled in Preferences. Turn it on if needed, then say Develop > Start Timeline Recording. That puts you into the Network Requests instrument. You can also get to it through Develop > Show Web Inspector.
- In Chrome, say View > Developer > Developer Tools, then go to the Network tab.
- IE has a very weak form of this, via Tools > Developer Tools > Profiler. It just gives a table of numbers, rather than a waterfall graph, so the information is there, but you can't just visually scan for long bars to find the slowest resources.

Answer (score 1):

You should use page speed plugin from google to check what data takes most of the time to load. It will show separate load times for images as well.

If you're using lots of small pngs I suggest you combining them into one image and manipulating the display via css background property since they are part of styling and not information. In that case - instead of few images only one will be loaded and reused through all elements. In this case even preloading of one image is really easy.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [CSS Sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) to combine all of your images into a single download? There are a number of [tools online](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/) to help you do this, and it will significantly reduce the number of HTTP requests required by your page.

Make sure you have [set the correct Expires header](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires) on your images to allow them to be cached.

Finally, take a look at [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) which can provide you with futher optimisation tips.